# find character before specified character

Tags: r, regex, substring, gsub

I want to use `gsub` to subtract characters.

```
# data
Column name
NORTH HANOVER TWP N J
MULLICA TWP NJ
VERONA N J
```

What I want is:

```
# result
Column name
NORTH HANOVER
MULLICA
VERONA
```

I try something like this:

```
gsub(" TWP.", "", "NORTH HANOVER TWP N J")
[1] "NORTH HANOVERN J"
```

I got the wrong result.
How can I fix my code?

Comment: What are the characters that mark the end of what you want, do you have a list of them? For the first two examples it's "TWP", but in the third is it just "N"? Or "N J"?

Comment: The logic isn't clear. Do you want to remove everything after "TWP" ? but then "VERONA" doesn't have that.

Comment: @RonakShah Yes. I want to remove everything after "TWP. However, there are some observations like "VERONA" which doesn't have "TWP". The end character does not necessarily include "J", maybe other characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit more general pattern (not saying it 100% fail proof)

```
cal <- c("NORTH HANOVER TWP N J","MULLICA TWP NJ","VERONA N J","Sierra Nevada TWP NJ")

gsub("\\sTWP\\s?N\\s?J.*|\\sN\\s?J.*","",cal)

#[1] "NORTH HANOVER" "MULLICA"       "VERONA"        "Sierra Nevada"
```

As the marked answer will fail.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following(considering that your actual Input is same as shown example).

```
gsub(" TWP.*| N.*","",cal)
```

Output will be as follows.

```
[1] "NORTH HANOVER" "NORTH HANOVER" "MULLICA"       "VERONA"
```

Where data is as follows.

```
cal <- data.frame(column_name=c("NORTH HANOVER","NORTH HANOVER TWP N J","MULLICA TWP NJ","VERONA N J"))
```

Comment: `gsub(" TWP.*| N.*","", cal$column_name)` works. Actually, not all observations include "N" in the dataset. It may contains others. But it works. Thanks